# Portable Mode Function in Visual Basic

Tags: arrays, vb.net, object, analysis

I'm trying to make my `Mode` function accept arrays of any type, and I'm not making any progress.  Here's what I've got now:

```
Private Function Mode(ByRef list As Object) As Object
        Dim array() As Object = {}
        Try
            array = CType(list, Object())
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Failed to cast array of Objects in Mode function!")
            Return Nothing
        End Try
        Dim uniqueObjects() As Integer = {array(0)}
        Dim frequency() As Integer = {1}
        For i As Integer = 0 To array.Length - 1
            For j As Integer = 0 To uniqueObjects.Length - 1 'loop through frequency
                If array(i) = uniqueObjects(j) Then
                    frequency(j) += 1
                    Exit For
                ElseIf j = uniqueObjects.Length - 1 Then
                    ReDim Preserve uniqueObjects(uniqueObjects.Length) 'add to unique objects array
                    uniqueObjects(uniqueObjects.Length - 1) = array(i)
                    ReDim Preserve frequency(frequency.Length) 'increment frequency
                    frequency(frequency.Length - 1) += 1
                End If
            Next
        Next

        Return uniqueObjects(System.Array.IndexOf(frequency, frequency.Max))
    End Function
```

I would normally get rid of the slow call to `CType` and just pass an array of Objects to the function, but It gives me a weird error when I pass an array of integers to the function:

> Error 1   Value of type '1-dimensional array of Integer' cannot be converted to '1-dimensional array of Object' because 'Integer' is not a reference type.    {filename}.vb   {line}  {column}    {project name}

This is turning out to be much trickier than I had expected.  Can anyone offer advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about making this a generic function?

```
Private Function Mode(Of T)(ByRef array As T()) As Object
    '...
End Function
```

Or

```
Private Function Mode(Of T)(ByRef array As T()) As T()
    '...
End Function
```

Then you do:

```
Dim obj As Object = Mode(Of Integer)({0, 1, 2, 3})
```

Or:

```
Dim obj As Integer() = Mode(Of Integer)({0, 1, 2, 3})
```

Comment: No, tried that too.  Then the line `If array(i) = uniqueObjects(j) Then` doesn't work.  It says operator = is not defined for objects of type T.

Comment: You need to change this to 'If (Object.Equals(array(i), uniqueObjects(j))) Then' And you ought to declare uniqueObjects as an array of T.